# $.inArray() retorno não esperado

Tags: javascript, jquery

Array **cookiesplit** contêm exatamente este conteúdo:

```js
_utma=246244038.1458519878.1422527074.1423248864.1423253252.8,    
__utmz=246244038.1422527074.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none), 
_ga=GA1.2.1458519878.1422527074, newsletter=ok, tracking202subid=30883, 
tracking202pci=6308836, _gat=1
```

Isto acima é um array, `cookiesplit` foi construido desta maneira abaixo:

```js
cookie = document.cookie;
cookiesplit = [];

cookiesplit = cookie.split(";");
```

Bom, veja, que em algum índice deste array temos o valor *newsletter=ok*, eu chequei isso fazendo um `$(cookiesplit).each(function(x){}`.

O problema é que está retornando **-1** quando verifico se contêm este valor *newsletter=ok*, veja o código que faz esta verificação:

```
res = $.inArray("newsletter=ok", cookiesplit); // res retorna -1
```

No meu entendimento, era para retornar o índice do valor *newsletter=ok*, pois ele existe, se não existi-se retornaria -1, mas como mostrei acima, o valor existe..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você está utilizando *Ponto e vírgula* como delimitador(`;`), porem o correto é uma *vírgula*(`,`).

```
var cookiesplit = array.split(',');
```

O método [`.InArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.inarray/) procura por um valor exato numa *array*, é retornado *-1* porque há um espaço em branco no início do valor. Portanto para achar esse valor você deve usar `" newsletter=ok"`.

```
var array ="_utma=246244038.1458519878.1422527074.1423248864.1423253252.8, 
  __utmz=246244038.1422527074.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none),
  _ga=GA1.2.1458519878.1422527074, newsletter=ok, tracking202subid=30883,
  tracking202pci=6308836, _gat=1";

var cookiesplit = array.split(',');
var res = $.inArray(" newsletter=ok", cookiesplit);

alert(res); // 3
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/qg73ns7u/1/)</kbd>

Se preferir, algo mais elegante:

```
var cookiesplit = $.map(array.split(','), $.trim);
var res = $.inArray("newsletter=ok", cookiesplit);

alert(res); // 3
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/z8w07t93/1/)</kbd>

Comment: Na verdade o único problema que você notou e ao aplicar resolveu, foi o espaço no inicio de newsletter=ok, eu estava procurando sem espaço.

Comment: Gostei de sua sugestão de usar trim para eliminar os espaços, obrigado, resolvido!